# Who first introduced Generalized Functions?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, math-history

I've been looking online but I can't seem to track down the original paper introducing generalized functions.  I suspect it should be by Schwartz (because of the Schwartz distributions) but I may definitely be wrong.

Comment: it was some physicist for sure, but Im not sure who. Schwartz developed the theory a lot time after that distributions already existed

Comment: Schwartz developed a rigorous framework for working with generalized functions, but the idea was introduced earlier by physicists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generalized functions were first introduced at the end of the 1920-s by P.A.M. Dirac in his research on quantum mechanics, in which he made systematic use of the concept of the $\delta$-function and its derivatives.

Reference: https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Generalized_function

Comment: I fixed the answer a bit; hope you did indeed mean the $\delta$-function. However, it is bad for an answer on history of science to lack any reference. Also, "please upvote" does not provide an answer to the question; please, stop adding it to the answer.

Comment: ok sure that's ok i will change the answer

Comment: pls upvote back my answer

Comment: thx so much thx

Comment: Thanks all.  This helps, I looked on Math. Encyl. but I wanted to double check :)

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#History) has a pretty informative section on the history of Dirac delta. To summarize:

- The idea itself can be traced to the times of Fourier: since
  $$f(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{ipx}\left(\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-ipq}f(q)dq\right)dp$$
  it is natural to (non-rigorously) rearrange as
  $$f(x) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{1}{2\pi}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{ipx}e^{-ipq}dp\right)f(q)dq = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\delta(x-q)f(q)dq$$
  where
  $$\delta(x-q)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{ip(x-q)}dp$$
  Though, it seems that no one actually expressed $\delta$ as a separate notion.
- Throughout the 19th century, many authors have explicitly used the idea of a *unit impulse* in PDE theory, either through Fourier transform as above, as a limit of shrinking Gaussians, or by some other means. This is intimately connected to the notion of [Green's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function).
- The term *delta function* was coined by Dirac in his book *The Principles of Quantum Mechanics* that was published in 1930. He seems to have used this just as a notational convenience. The name *delta* comes from resemblance to [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta).
- The modern form of generalized functions, i.e. [*distributions*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)) defined as linear functionals on spaces of appropriate test functions, originate in works of Sobolev, later developed and extended by Schwartz in 1940s.